# Adjusted cosine similarity

Tags: php, arrays, similarity, trigonometry

I'm trying to code **[adjusted cosine similarity](http://www10.org/cdrom/papers/519/node14.html)** in PHP.

I built my data like this :

```
$data[UserID][ItemID] = Rating
```

data example :

```
$data[1][1] = 5;
$data[1][2] = 3;
$data[1][3] = 4;

$data[2][1] = 3;
$data[2][2] = 2;
$data[2][4] = 3;
$data[2][5] = 3;

$data[3][1] = 4;
$data[3][3] = 3;
$data[3][5] = 5;

$data[4][1] = 1;
$data[4][2] = 4;
$data[4][4] = 2;
$data[4][5] = 1;

$data[5][3] = 4;
$data[5][4] = 3;
```

I want to write a function to calculate the adjusted cosine of 2 items, like

```
adjusted_cosine(itemID1,itemID2)
```

Comment: Sorry, mate. We're not here to write your code for you. If you first try putting this together, we might be able to help correct it.

Comment: hehehe, it's not homework. I just want to build recommender system in my web. But I only build the pearson similarity one. But in many source that tell the adjusted cosine is better than pearson.

But thank you for your comment. I'll apreciate it. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this ought to do it:

```
sim(i,j) {
    item1 = 0
    item2 = 0

    // calculate the sums for the ith and jth items
    // minus each users' avg rating.
    for (k = 0; k < length(data); k++) {
        item1 += (data[k][i] - avg(data[k]))
        item2 += (data[k][j] - avg(data[k]))
    }

    result (item1*item2)/(sqrt(item1*item1)*sqrt(item2*item2))
    return result
}
```

You'll still need to implement the average function but I suppose a simple mean will do for that.

Comment: Note that a simple mean over i and j will transform this similarity in the pearson correlation function.